# Textbox cursor set to beginning of text when updated from DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple `TextBox` control that is bound to a `string` property in an instance of a type. Like so:

```
textbox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", m_Configuration, propertyName));
```

When the property in the instance is updated, it gets displayed in the `TextBox`. But, the cursor position in the `TextBox` stays at the beginning.

Is there a way to have it automatically be at the end of whatever text is there?

I know I could manually code the TextBox to reset its cursor position using `ScrollToCaret()`. But, that means, I would have to type this same code 30 different `TextBox` control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to code this behavior multiple times, why not inherit from TextBox and add the code. I think there is no other way than to do it like that.

Comment: And here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z(v=VS.90).aspx in case you need help getting started.